# What is the benefit of security images, like on bank website logins?

Tags: security

Several sites (I remember Yahoo did this too, back when I used my Yahoo account) such as Bank of America show a SiteKey or similar image the user chooses after they enter their username, but before they enter their password.  Ostensibly, this ensures the login page is unique to each user, and therefore a phisher can't just show a static login page that looks like the bank's site, but what's stopping them from simply hitting the bank's site in the background and forwarding the image (or other security challenge) right to the user?  I'll grant, it makes the phisher's job slightly harder, but it really doesn't seem that valuable to me.  What's the rationale for this behavior?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed, but I edited the title, perhaps it now sounds more inviting?  I think this is a legitimate question for SO - I would like to understand this security pattern better.

Comment: I am agree with dimo414 this should be open.

Answer (score 1):

If a single server keeps hitting their site requesting the images for different userids (especially one where the users haven't logged in from before), it will be pretty suspicious, so it's harder for a Phisher to hide.

Comment: i don't see this argument valid. there are plenty ISP that offers private ip to their users. if such users log in to the bank, the bank sees always the same ip - the ip of their ISP. it looks very similar to phisher

Comment: Wouldn't be hard to kick it off as an AJAX request instead (might even look more secure to the user, seeing the image come in separately), but even if a phisher runs it from their own server(s), watching traffic patterns isn't enough - between public hotspots, proxies, botnets, and other IP sources, phishers have long ago been able to evade traffic pattern checks.